# Error when generating token to get access to the docusign for postman

Tags: java, api, postman, docusignapi, integration

I'm trying to generate an access token following the docusign documentation, but when it arrives at the part of the sequence incorporated in the url, I can't generate the signature compatible with what is requested RSA-256.

This is the token that returns in the url, how should i proceed to generate the correct token to get the access token to the methods.

**eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQsAAAABAAYABwCAWdDpkO_YSAgAgOVWMZHv2EgCAC8x_aWgjDdEpqZZDhWJAksVAAEAAAAYAAIAAAAFAAAAHQAAAA0AJAAAADY4ZDFlYTk3LTk5ZDMtNDM4MS05MmY5LTg3ZTdlMWFiMWIzOCIAJAAAADY4ZDFlYTk3LTk5ZDMtNDM4MS05MmY5LTg3ZTdlMWFiMWIzODAAgFnQ6ZDv2EgSAAEAAAALAAAAaW50ZXJhY3RpdmU3AF2EwqcBnYBHm1UeBpeUZIA.5AiJJl_ugWRECf7jTD7DchgUZV_Mk30cXJwmPAMkThH9dwtu2A9ehMwkARi0QvmSIoo1Pk-gUj2U_GMAk9flG5IAHVYIPcy9hbWMcRyr7RMYldKqvh2V8UH4-Uv5BBQNHkwQ36spfuYFaafDLHVq86Mt91m4MK-ZByRzZkboQKNHCaNjani-hPNTlhHkkWuKOPTu8R9GY24TvNhRu9ILYRgRUFsXG3E-ptNFTyhdKM8_RuNQrqed9ZA2oPo4WjNm-b1VIFdVElU3duniBS-inWJD2ifzp8N1zKFm_Nv8UMjpZOtitdW0M4QQ7rXG6Q-6xoNE_ODWQZUWsD2mQaz4_A**

Is there any configuration in the sandbox that may be generating this token wrongly? Whatever it is i need help to generate this token in postman, because i need to integrate with my API and test the methods before coding.

Comment: are you trying to use Auth Code Grant or JWT?

Comment: I am using  JWT grant authentication.

Comment: are you using the Java SDK package?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you generate a token with Postman using Authorization Code Grant:

1. Open a browser and go to this URL (after you updated it with your info) [https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7BiKey%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bcallback%7D)
2. If it's configured correctly, you should now be redirected back to your redirectUri with an additional URL parameter called code.
3. Copy/paste this code into your Postman application. You would have to copy/paste the code that you obtained from the URL parameter into the Body key/value pair (replacing the {{codeFromUrl}} value). Note that the code is valid for two minutes only. If you don’t send this information to DocuSign quickly enough, you will have to obtain a new code again. Hit the Send button at the top of Postman to make the call to DocuSign.

Now, you indicated you are using Java, so another approach for you may be to use our [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) and select Java. That will take care of all the Auth configuration for you.

Comment: I am trying to do this, but then giving a 400 error, but in my opinion I think that the first access token is not generating correctly, how can I validate this?

Comment: so when you generate the URL in 1 you get 400? that means you didn't set up your URL correct. Or are you at step 3?

Comment: I'm in step 3, when I already have the client's token to get access

Comment: and what URL are you trying to call in step 3?

Comment: this url: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

Comment: So you need to ensure two things:
1. In the body of the request, you have the code you copy/pasted from step 1 that you got.
2. In the header you have the Authorization header that has "Basic and then the values of your clientId and ClientToken encoded together